# Attemping to install Ubuntu 12.10 onto UEFI Windows 8 Asus laptop results in black screen after ¨try ubuntu without installing¨ and ¨install ubuntu¨

Tags: installation, 12.10, screen, windows-8, uefi

I´ve been trying to follow every guide I see about installing ubuntu onto a UEFI laptop, but so far nothing has worked. Basically I want to overwrite windows 8 with ubuntu, so I never have to see it again. I installed ubuntu 12.10 64 bit with pendrive onto a USB, went into the computer BIOS, set the usb drive as the priority, disabled fastboot and secure boot. I then get to a screen that gives the options ¨Try Ubuntu without installing¨, ¨Install Ubuntu¨ and ¨Check disk for defects¨. It´s the kind of screen that´s a very basic black screen with those options, no Ubuntu logo or any other options, except for going to the command line and etc.

Upon pressing any of the 3 options the screen then goes blank, with the backlight still on and continues to stay like that forever until I turn it off.

I´ve tried everywhere to look for a solution, but most answers, including the nomodeset fix, can´t apply to this because there´s no available option for it.

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/15939

Comment: If [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) does not help, please edit this question so it explains in detail everything you did (from that question) and exactly what happened.

Comment: This can happen sometimes, I suggest you flash your usb again.